# if inappbrowser is already open, stay on the current url and reject any other opening request

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

I have a link that opens in the inappbrowser and when i proceed with the webpage that is loaded in the inappbrowser , any other link should not get opened if one link is already running in inappbrowser.

Whereas when i click other link, it loads over the previous running inappbrowser and i clearly do not want that

Please help!!!

this is the source code

```
universalLinks.subscribe(null, function (eventData) {
   ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(eventData.url, '_blank', 'location=yes');

   setTimeout(function () {
      ref.close();
   }, 320000);

   });
```

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, or any new code you've tried, will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: @MikeM. My bad..do you have any answer for the question??